# Linq query using contains is not working

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to use a query in LINQ and use a function that works like "LIKE" in TSQL.
For example:

```
 SELECT salary 
 FROM employees 
 WHERE last_name LIKE 'R%';
```

I am trying to make a query in LINQ to an Oracle DB. The query seems to work very well when I am not using .Contains() and when I add it I get 0 records back.
I am not sure if Contains() is the correct method to do this. 
Here is my LINQ code:

```
 var queryOracle = (from TS in dbOracle.BI_TYPE_SERVICE
                                join MS in dbOracle.BI_MTR_SRV on TS.BI_ACCT equals MS.BI_ACCT
                                join SL in dbOracle.BI_SRV_LOC on MS.BI_SRV_LOC_NBR equals SL.BI_SRV_LOC_NBR
                                join C in dbOracle.BI_CONSUMER on TS.BI_ACCT equals C.BI_ACCT
                                join P in dbOracle.BI_PERSONAL on C.BI_CUST_NBR equals P.BI_CUST_NBR
                                join STR in dbOracle.BI_SRV_STAT_REF on TS.BI_SRV_STAT_CD equals STR.BI_SRV_STAT_CD
                               where  P.BI_FORMAT_NAME.Contains("Tom")

                               select new
                              {
                              LocationID = SL.BI_SRV_MAP_LOC,
                              MeterNumber = MS.BI_MTR_NBR,
                              AccountNumber = TS.BI_ACCT,
                              ServiceStatCD = TS.BI_SRV_STAT_CD,
                              ServiceStatus = STR.BI_SRV_STAT_DESC,
                              Name = P.BI_FORMAT_NAME,
                              ServiceAddr = SL.BI_ADDR1,
                              ServiceCity = SL.BI_CITY,
                              CustomerNumber = C.BI_CUST_NBR,
                              ServiceCNTY = SL.BI_CNTY_CD,
                              ServiceTOWN = SL.BI_TOWN_CD,
                              HomeAreaCode = P.BI_HOME_AREA_CD,
                              HomePhone = P.BI_HOME_PHN,
                              BusAreaCode = P.BI_BUS_AREA_CD,
                              BusPhone = P.BI_BUS_PHN,
                              MobileAreaCode = P.BI_MOBL_AREA_CD,
                              MobilePhone = P.BI_MOBL_PHN
                          }).Take(10);
```

Comment: `Contains()` should work, though it might be too much.  For that pattern, you should be using  `StartsWith()`.  Though, it wouldn't matter if you're not getting any results. Are you sure that there are corresponding rows for each of those joined tables?

Comment: Thank you Jeff, it has corresponding rows and it is working now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Contains` should work as it checks for a substring. It is equal to executing the sql statement `where BI_FORMAT_NAME LIKE '%Tom%'`

But if need records for `LIKE 'Tom%'` condition, You may use `StartsWith` method.

```
where  P.BI_FORMAT_NAME.StartsWith("Tom")
```

It should work as long as your LINQ query without the `where` clause is returning records with `BI_FORMAT_NAME` column has values like `"Tom"` or `"TomSomeThingElse"`

**The LINQ methods for different SQL `like`clause use cases are**

1. `LIKE '%To%'`   **-->**  `Contains("To")`
2. `LIKE 'Tom%'`   **-->**  `StartsWith("Tom")`
3. `LIKE '%Tom'`   **-->**  `EndsWith("Tom")`