# How to retrive list of posts when searching in tags table [ASP MVC]

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to make a search for post via tags , for example when I write in the search box "ASP" I will search for post they have same tags and return them as a list of post ...

Here is my tags table :
[image: BooksTag]

[image: Tags]

Also here is my book class :

```
[Table("Book")]
public partial class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int Book_id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name ="User Name")]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string User_ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Title Name")]
    [StringLength(70,MinimumLength =3)]
    public string Book_name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Edition")]
    [Range(1, 20)]
    public int Edition { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Category Name")]
    public int Category_id { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]    
    [Display(Name = "Publish Date")]
    public DateTime Publish_date { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Author Name")]
    public string Author_name { get; set; }


    [StringLength(128)]
    [Display(Name = "Cover Image")]
    public string Book_Image { get; set; }


    [StringLength(128,MinimumLength =8)]
    [Url]
    [Display(Name = "Download Link")]
    public string Download_Link { get; set; }


    [StringLength(250)]
    [Display(Name = "Upload Pdf")]
    public string pdf_file { get; set; }


    [AllowHtml]
    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string Book_Description { get; set; }


    public int View_Count { set; get; }

    [StringLength(250,MinimumLength =2,ErrorMessage ="Min Tags Input lenght is 2 char")]
    [Display(Name = "Tags")]
    public virtual string TagsListing { get; set; }


    public virtual IList<Tag> Tags
    { get; set; }
    public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Also tag class :

```
public class Tag
{
    public virtual int Id
    { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name
    { get; set; }

    public virtual string UrlSlug
    { get; set; }

    public virtual string Description
    { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Book> Books
    { get; set; }
}
```

I just simply want to see if the search term that the visitor searched for can be founded in tags table , and return list of books related to the same tag..

thanks

Comment: Something like `db.Tags.Where(t => t.Name.Equals(input)).SelectMany(t => t.Books).Distinct()` ?  It's impossible for anybody here to know what specific code you would use since you're not showing any information about your data access code.

Comment: @David , I updated my question and added my book & tag classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using LINQ

```
var searchTerm = "Swift";
var postList = db.Books.Where(s => s.Tags.Any(g => g.Name.Contains(searchTerm))).ToList();
```

`Contains` will do a SQL equivalent of `LIKE '%Swift%'` . You can also try `StartsWith` or `EndsWith` [as needed.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34777091/40521)

Comment: the TagsBooks Actually is not exists in my context because I used code first , and when I created the relation many to many in my classes , the tagsbooks table created in sql management only , but as a class is not found or exists

Comment: How does your entities (Book and Tag) looks like ?

Comment: Error CS1061 'SmartBookLibraryModel' does not contain a definition for 'TagBooks' and no extension method 'TagBooks' accepting a first argument of type 'SmartBookLibraryModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I updated my question and added the book and tag class model

Comment: See my updated answer.Next time make sure to include the relevant information in the first post.

Comment: Thanks it's working , and sorry about missing to add my classes . Good day for you sir