# A method in controller to return two json objects

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc

```
Public JsonResult GetDetails()
{ 
  List<Cust> Customers = new List<Cust>();
  Customers = GetCustomerDetails();
  var name = Customers.Select(e => new{e.custname}).Distinct().ToList();
  var dept =  Customers.Select(e => new{e.deptname}).Distinct().ToList();
  var response = new{CustomerNames = name, CustomerDepartments = dept};
  return Json(response, JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet();
}
```

I have this above method returning a json object, now this method has to return a subset of this response along with the one its returning, is it possible to do a filter on department type and return two jon objects from same method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. You can add one more property to your anonymous object and return that.

```
public JsonResult GetDetails()
{ 
  var customers = GetCustomerDetails();
  var names = customers.Select(e => new {e.custname}).Distinct().ToList();
  var depts =  customers.Select(e => new { e.deptname}).Distinct().ToList();
  var deptSubSet = depts.Where(f=>f.deptname=="IT").ToList(); 
  //replace this with your condition

  var response = new {  CustomerNames = names, 
                        CustomerDepartments = depts,
                        FilteredDepartments = deptSubSet 
                     };
   return Json(response, JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet();
}
```

Replace the `Where` condition linq code with whatever where clause you need to use to get the sub set.

BTW, The result is not going to be an array, It will be an object with 3 properties. The value of those properties will be an array.

Comment: thank you so so much for your reply...is it possible to select all those customers with department name IT and whose name starts with 'N', can we merge two results.

Comment: Yes. you can use [StartsWith](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777044/linq-query-using-contains-is-not-working/34777091#34777091) extension method

Comment: but how can I merge both names and dept and store it in a property of the above response object.

Comment: The annonymous object will have 3 properties .CustomerNames ,CustomerDepartments  and FilteredDepartments

Comment: Yes, I need customer names which starts with N and are present in filteredDepartments.

Comment: `filteredDepartments` is a collection of object with `deptName` property You should do your where clause (use StartsWith) on a data set which has both the properties (customer name and departments). May be you need to use a join. Without knowing your table structure i can only suggest this much.

Comment: Thank you Shyju, I am able to get the desired results. Thank you so much!